# Set buffer radius in metric units in qGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, units, ftools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is up with QGIS buffer tool units?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23856/what-is-up-with-qgis-buffer-tool-units)

A similar question to this one has already been asked [How to change the unit of measure from degrees to meters in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13023/qgis-change-unit-of-measure-from-degrees-to-meters), but none of the steps suggested has worked for me.

I have a data set with over 37000 points. I would like buffer the points with 5km, 10km, and 15km radii using f-tools, dissolving the buffers to see how the total surface under the buffers evolves.

By default, my qGIS has the CRS set at WGS84 (settings-> project properties). My shape file with the points was also initially set at WGS84.

As I mentioned, I would like to draw the buffers with the radii set in metric units, however, the units are always in degrees.

I have tried adjusting my qGIS project settings both before and after opening the shape file, modifying the shape file settings (always changing both to EPSG:3414 - SVY21 / Singapore TM as this is data for Western Malaysia) directly, etc.

Somehow, I always get buffers in degrees rather than metric units.

Comment: " modifying the shape file settings " how are you doing this step?

Comment: By right-cliking on the layer in question, and then going either into "set layer CRS" and "set project CRS from layer", I have tried both.

Comment: Try doing Right Click -> Save As.. and re-save the layer with a different CRS.