# Choosing appropriate projected coordinate system for Africa

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance, africa

I am using the NNjoin tool to compute the distance between points and a multilinestring. Both layers are in CRS 4326 and cover most of Africa.

I've understood that I need to reproject my layers to a projected coordinate system to be able to get the distance between the points in metres rather than degrees.

How can I choose which projected coordinate system to use?

Comment: Convert them to EPSG:3857

Comment: No, Web Mercator is the last projection you want to use for distance calculation even within a kilometer of the Equator.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a custom [Chamberlin trimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamberlin_trimetric_projection) projected CRS.

---

From [Snyder, John P. Map projections: A working manual. USGS Publications Warehouse. 1987](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395):

> The Chamberlin Trimetric projection is an approximate "three-point equidistant" projection, constructed so that distances from three chosen points to any
>   other point on the map are approximately correct. The latter distances cannot be
>   exactly true, but the projection is a compromise which the National Geographic
>   Society uses as a standard projection for maps of most continents. This projection
>   was geometrically constructed by the Society, of which Wellman Chamberlin
>   (1908-76) was chief cartographer for many years.

---

For the [Wikimedia example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chamberlin_trimetric_projection_SW.jpg):

[image: 1]

> Africa on Chamberlin trimetric projection. 10° graticule, anchor points at (22°N, 0°), (22°N, 45°E), and (22°S, 22°30'E).

---

You can create the custom PROJ.4 string for the [Chamberlin trimetric conversion method](https://proj.org/operations/projections/chamb.html) for a WGS84 datum:

`+proj=chamb +lat_1=22 +lon_1=0 +lat_2=22 +lon_2=45 +lat_3=-22 +lon_3=22.5 +datum=WGS84 +type=crs`

And ask its WKT2:2019 string with:

```
C:\>projinfo "+proj=chamb +lat_1=22 +lon_1=0 +lat_2=22 +lon_2=45 +lat_3=-22 +lon_3=22.5 +datum=WGS84 +type=crs"
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=chamb +lat_1=22 +lon_1=0 +lat_2=22 +lon_2=45 +lat_3=-22 +lon_3=22.5 +datum=WGS84 +type=crs

WKT2:2019 string:
PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6326]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8901]]],
    CONVERSION["unknown",
        METHOD["PROJ chamb"],
        PARAMETER["lat_1",22,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        PARAMETER["lon_1",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        PARAMETER["lat_2",22,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        PARAMETER["lon_2",45,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        PARAMETER["lat_3",-22,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        PARAMETER["lon_3",22.5,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change te projected coordinate system in QGIS of the project by using ctrl+shift+P --> CRS

[image]

To change the projection of a layer, right click on the layer in the layers pane --> Set CRS --> Set Layer CRS.

[image]

Somebody before you already asked the same question.

[Changing unit of measure from degrees to meters in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13023/changing-unit-of-measure-from-degrees-to-meters-in-qgis)

Comment: I doubt if NNJOIN will recognize that the *project's* CRS has changed; most likely it will rely on the *layer* CRS, and will thus output gibberish.  Much preferable to re-project the layer, as in  Gabriel's answer.