# Appropriate distance and CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance, buffer

I want to use `buffer` function using miles or kilometers in Louisiana. I checked [Changing unit of measure from degrees to meters in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13023/changing-unit-of-measure-from-degrees-to-meters-in-qgis). The original CRS is `EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic` and the distance is reasonable in Picture 1. I changed to `EPSG:32615 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 15N - Projected`. But, distance parameters do not work (Picture 2). How do I fix this problem?

Picture 1
[image: Figure1]

Picture 2
[image: Figure2]

Comment: How did you change the crs? Did you set it or reproject the layer?

Comment: I use ```Layer CRS``` and ```Set Layer CRS...```. Then select mentioned CRS.

Comment: You must use the tool:  
toolbox >> reproject layer
and define the new CRS

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348521/layer-disappears-when-changing-from-crs-in-degrees-to-crs-in-meters-in-qgis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the tool: toolbox >> reproject layer and define the new CRS

[image]